# Split string on n or more whitespaces

Tags: python, tokenize, text-processing

I have a string like that:

```
sentence = 'This is   a  nice    day'
```

I want to have the following output:

```
output = ['This is', 'a  nice',  'day']
```

In this case, I split the string on `n`=3 or more whitespaces and this is why it is split like it is shown above.

How can I efficiently do this for any `n`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try using Python's regex split:

```
sentence = 'This is   a  nice day'
output = re.split(r'\s{3,}', sentence)
print(output)

['This is', 'a  nice day']
```

To handle this for an actual variable `n`, we can try:

```
n = 3
pattern = r'\s{' + str(n) + ',}'
output = re.split(pattern, sentence)
print(output)

['This is', 'a  nice day']
```

Comment: AFAIK, this is the only solution that gives what op desired: n _or more_ white spaces. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use the basic .split() function:

```
sentence = 'This is   a  nice day'
n = 3
sentence.split(' '*n)

>>> ['This is', 'a  nice day']
```

Comment: This keeps some undesired whitespaces, run it with the sentence at my edited post above. You split on **n** whitespaces not **n or more** as I look for.

Comment: Indeed, i missunderstood your question. I keep the answer here as it can help other people later!

Comment: Cool no worries :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also split by `n` spaces, strip the results and remove empty elements (if there are several such long spaces that would produce them):

```
sentence = 'This is   a  nice day'
n = 3
parts = [part.strip() for part in sentence.split(' ' * n) if part.strip()]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x = 'This is   a  nice day'    
result = [i.strip() for i in x.split(' ' * 3)]
print(result)

['This is', 'a  nice day']
```